# Overleaf cannot render any LaTex

Tags: overleaf, compilation-error

I'm new to overleaf and I'm trying to render a basic document and I get:

"PDF Rendering Error Something went wrong while rendering this PDF."

[image: Example of the error I get]

Does anyone know what might cause this? I have tried several document so far.

The logs say:

> No errors, good job!

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) Overleaf should have a button somewhere so you can see the actual log, without tht information we cannot help

Comment: @daleif The logs say "No errors, good job!"

Comment: (I'm on support staff at Overleaf.) One thing to try is to change the "PDF Viewer" setting (accessed using the Overleaf menu in the upper left) from "built-in" to "native". If that works and the preview renders, the most likely cause of the problem is that something is blocking compiles.sharelatex.com, which is where the previews are generated. Usually a browser extension is responsible for blocking this domain, but aggressive proxies or other network security may also be at play.

Comment: I sometimes get that also. My solution is to recompile the document.

Comment: Not working for me, but thanks!

Comment: @JohnDoe bummer, that is the most common cause of this. If that didn't change anything, it's probably best for you to contact us at support@overleaf.com because it may be something specific to your project that's causing this.

Comment: @PaulGessler I don't have access to sharelatex.com due to a firewall. Anything we can do to get around that?

Comment: (I'm on support staff at Overleaf.) @JohnDoe just for completeness, and in case anyone finds this question via searching: This problem occurred in certain network configurations and should now be resolved as part of the integration of the Overleaf and ShareLaTeX platforms. If you still see the PDF Rendering Error, please contact us at Overleaf Support using our website contact form (in the top bar, click "Help" and then "Contact us" or email us directly at `support@overleaf.com`.)

Comment: I had the same problem. And tried to fix the issue following @PaulGessler, but it didn't help me out. I went ahead and deleted the cookies related to Overleaf and refreshed my page, which seems like fixed the issue.

Comment: I had this problem as well. In my case, I was working on a specific document when suddenly the PDF stopped rendering. What solved it for me was to comment out the last paragraph I wrote, recompile (success!), fix any LaTeX issues, and then recompile again (success!).

Comment: In my case, I had an extension installed in my browser blocking overleaf rendering.

Comment: Sometimes this happens because of some extensions. In my case, the issue with the download manager extension I have disabled it and things worked well.